# How to remove a number after another number with comma outside parentheses using XSLT 3.1 "replace" function

Tags: regex, replace, xsd

I am finding numbers more then two with comma but my regex find numbers inside or outside parentheses. How to find numbers not inside parentheses.

**Regex used**

```
([0-9]+, ){2,}
```

**String**

```
Albemarle Paper Co. v Moody (1975) 422 US 405, 425, 95 S Ct 2362
```

**Expected Result**

```
Albemarle Paper Co. v Moody (1975) 422 US 405, 95 S Ct 2362
```

In particular, my XML looks like

```
<root>
<p><styled-content><italic>Agarwal v Johnson </italic>(1979) 25 C3d 932, 942, overruled on *6 other grounds in <italic>White v Ultramar, Inc.</italic> (1999) 21 C4th 563</styled-content></p>
</root>
```

Here is the XSL template with the regex and replace function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="replace(p/styled-content, '[0-9]+(?:, [-0-9]+)+,(?![^()]*\))', '')"/></p>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you use `xs:assertions`? Or are you confined to XSD 1.0 only?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sir, I want some number replace when it comes without inside parentheses but I have found some syntax error. E.g. (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/18).

Comment: I have no idea, but `<xsl:value-of select="replace(p/styled-content, '([0-9]+(, [-0-9]+)+,[^()]*\))|[0-9]+(, [-0-9]+)+,', '$1')"/>` seems to work to some extent. It might turn out good enough for you here. What is the regex engine used in this case, I wonder?

Comment: Does `<xsl:value-of select="replace(p/styled-content, '(\([^()]*\))|([0-9]+, ){2,}', '$1')"/>` work as expected?

Comment: First is found the numbers not inside parentheses after that I want only return 1st value e.g. "Albemarle Paper Co. v Moody (1975) 422 US 405, 425, 95 S Ct 2362" replace after We want "Albemarle Paper Co. v Moody (1975) 422 US 405, 95 S Ct 2362" remove only "425". if I have used then working fine but this regex `([0-9]+?,\s?)([0-9]+?,\s)` effects on inside parentheses. Demo: regex (https://regex101.com/r/Ih65Sl/1) and XSLT fiddle e.g. (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/19) first line replace OK but with working 2nd line inside parentheses.

Comment: Does `<xsl:value-of select="replace(styled-content, '(\([^()]*\))|([0-9]+,)\s*[0-9]+,?', '$1$2')"/>` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks for given me proper solution Nice Work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213998/discussion-between-wiktor-stribizew-and-sandy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using XSLT 3.1 [`replace` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace).

You may use

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(styled-content, '(\([^()]*\))|([0-9]+,)\s*[0-9]+,', '$1$2')"/>
```

This is a [demo of how the replace works in this case](https://regex101.com/r/sKR6Gk/3).

**Details**

- `(\([^()]*\))` - Capturing group #1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern): a `(`, any 0+ chars other than `)` and `(` and then `)`
- `|` - or
- `([0-9]+,)` - Capturing group #2 (`$2`): 1+ digits and a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `,`  - a comma.

The replacement is the contents of Group 1 and 2.

Comment: Sir please edit if last number not comma then not replace. e.g. (https://regex101.com/r/sKR6Gk/2) after that working fine. may be `(\([^()]*\))|([0-9]+,)\s*[0-9]+,`

Comment: @Sandy Just make the last comma obligatory, remove `?`

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE**: Now, that you added the XSD tag, note you cannot use a lookahead in [XML Schema regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html): "*Particularly noteworthy is the complete absence of anchors like the caret and dollar, word boundaries, and lookaround.*".

XML Schema 1.1 supports `xs:assertion`s. With the following, you can assure `123, 345, 567 text` matches and `(123, 345, 567) text` and `(123, 345, 567) 123, 345, 567 text` do not:

```
<xs:element name="your_element">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:assertion test="not(matches($value, '.*\([^()]*([0-9]+, ){2,}[^()]*\).*'))"/>
      <xs:assertion test="matches($value, '.*([0-9]+, ){2,}.*')"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

The answer below will work for other engines that work with lookaheads:

```
[0-9]+(?:, [-0-9]+)+(?![^()]*\))
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/2Q3Q8L/1). It will find sequence of comma-separated numbers not followed with non-parentheses characters up to a close parenthesis.

If comma must come after the second or more numbers, just add it:

```
[0-9]+(?:, [-0-9]+)+,(?![^()]*\))
                    ^
                    |___ HERE
```

See [updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Q3Q8L/3)

Comment: its also matches 95

Comment: @Sandy did u want to match 95?

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib It doesn't match 95.

Comment: @Booboo check his demo

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib I have Edited `[0-9]+(?:, [-0-9]+,)+(?![^()]*\))` but My Oxygen error show "Syntax error at char 21 in regular expression: No expression before quantifier".

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib It's matching `405, 425, 95,` (look to the right to see the groups). However, it also matches `405, 95`, which does not have a trailing comma and I don't think that is what the OP asked for. Also, it does not match `1, 2, )`.

Comment: @Sandy If there must be comma  after you can use `[0-9]+(?:, [-0-9]+)+,(?![^()]*\))`, see https://regex101.com/r/2Q3Q8L/3

Comment: Sir, I have found syntax error. Can you check please syntax error (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/16) if in I am remove this part then working some syntax error of the part `(?![^(]*\))`.

Comment: @Sandy XML Schema regex does not support lookarounds. Both  solutions will fail for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex engine supports `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`, then this regex does a better job of ensuring the numbers are not within parenthesis:

```
(?x)                    # Verbose flag
    (?:\([^()]*)        # Match '( ....'
    (?:\d+,\ ){2,}      # Our regex in '( ..... )'
    (?:[^()]*\))        # Match  '..... )'
    (*SKIP)(*FAIL)      # Fail the first alternative
|                       # Second alternative
    (?:\d+,\ ){2,}      # Our regex not enclosed in '( ... )'
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L1EMLq/2/)

**Old Solution**

When a regex problem is posed, the OP is supposed to state the language being used because different (1) different languages support different subsets of the regex specification and (2) depending on the complexity of the problem, it may take more take some procedural code to fully solve the problem or at least to solve it in a simple fashion.

The solutions posed so far do not fully solve the problem of determining whether the numbers are enclosed withing parenthesis. They take a simplified approach of looking to see whether the numbers are followed by a right parenthesis, and this causes false results.

The solution is to have a regex that looks for two alternate sub-regex patterns: (1) numbers within parenthesis and (2) numbers and then determine which sub-pattern was matched and to only use matches from the seconds sub-pattern. Here I am using Python:

```
import re

text = """Albemarle Paper Co. v Moody (1975) 422 US 405, 425, 95 S Ct 2362 (Booboo)
Albemarle Paper Co. v Moody (1975) 422 US 405, 95 S Ct 2362
Aerotek, Inc. v Johnson Group Staffing Co. (July 30, 2013, C067652) 2013 Cal Unpub Lexis 5424:"""

r_ex = re.compile(r"""
        (?:\([^)]*)             # Match '( ....'
        (?P<R1>(\d+,\s){2,})    # Our regex in capture group R1
        (?:[^)]*\))             # Match  '..... )'
    |                           # Second alternative
        (?P<R2>(\d+,\s){2,})    # Our regex not enclosed in '( ... )' in capture group R2
        """, flags=re.X)

for m in r_ex.finditer(text):
    if m.lastgroup == 'R2': # only chose second alternative matches
        print(m.group())
```

Prints:

```
405, 425,
```

**Update**

While I was writing this it seems that the OP did add a language, `xsd`, which probably does not provide for procedural code. I will leave this answer anyway for whatever it is worth.